# How to format post reqest body

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express, post

So i post a data from a nodejs server

POST REQUEST

```js
{
    "id": "285104348274884628",
    "username": "TEST USERNAME",
    "apiKey": "5WA8G5LUYPJB8RII64RE443EFTTY-PY"
}
```

My Post Code In Express Server:

```js
app.post('/api/v1/admin/users', (req, res) => {
    const users = req.body;
    user = JSON.stringify(users)
    userModel.push(user);
    res.status(201).json({
        error: false,
        message: 'Created User',
        time: 0
    })
});
```

And I try to GET the data in express server

```js
app.get('/api/v1/admin/users', (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).send(userModel)
});
```

And my problem is when i get the data is response like this

```
[
  {
    "id": "655881699304931368",
    "username": "KASKUSTTV",
    "apiKey": "5WA7G5LUYPJB8RII64RE443EFTTY-PY"
  },
  "{\"{\\r\\n    \\\"id\\\": \\\"285104348274884628\\\",\\r\\n    \\\"username\\\": \\\"TEST USERNAME\\\",\\r\\n    \\\"apiKey\\\": \\\"5WA8G5LUYPJB8RII64RE443EFTTY-PY\\\"\\r\\n}\":\"\"}"
]
```

How can i make it response like this?

```
[
  {
    "id": "655881699304931368",
    "username": "KASKUSTTV",
    "apiKey": "5WA7G5LUYPJB8RII64RE443EFTTY-PY"
  },
  {
    "id": "285104348274884628",
    "username": "TEST USERNAME",
    "apiKey": "5WA8G5LUYPJB8RII64RE443EFTTY-PY"
  }
]
```

Comment: try using JSON.parse() instead of JSON.stringify()?

Comment: `req.body` is already a string. You need to parse it to get the object from the JSON.

Comment: It says `Cannot convert object to primitive value at JSON.parse`

Comment: Do you have to stringify in the POST code? It might be inserting wrong into your data model. Try removing the stringify.

Comment: nvm i forgot to set the contentType application/json, but ty for help

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to stringify it, push array instead.

```
app.post('/api/v1/admin/users', (req, res) => {
    const users = req.body;
    userModel.push(users);
    res.status(201).json({
        error: false,
        message: 'Created User',
        time: 0
    })
});
```